# Why does my HTML number input get stuck with step 0.010000000000000009?

Tags: html, input

When I create an HTML `<input type="number"/>` with `step="0.010000000000000009"`. I can only click the button to increase the value once to fill in the `min` value and then only once for the first increase by the step value, then it gets stuck at this value and further clicks have no effect. I can only reproduce this with `min="1.2" max="1.3"`.

All other combinations of `min`, `max` and `step` I tried allow to click the button multiple times until it reaches max in the defined steps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>input with decimal step</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" min="1.2" max="1.3" step="0.010000000000000009"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Firefox lets you click twice before getting stuck.

Comment: No repro in Chrome. If this is FF only, then a bug report might be warranted.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic comes to my mind.

Comment: @Dominik I wasn't precise enough in my question, edited

Comment: I'm not sure it's a necessarily a _bug_ in Firefox, it's more that Chrome is being more lenient. According to MDN, the `max` values, if specified, must be equal to `min + ( n * step )` - if I'm reading their (not-exactly-clear) remarks correctly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step

Comment: @hanshenrik Looks like a bug, or rather: a likely intentional spec-violation by Chrome, not Firefox. See that Firefox sets `HTMLInputElement.validity.stepMismatch` but Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that, according to the HTML5 Living Specification, your `<input />` element "suffers from step-mismatch":

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-step-attribute
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-min-zero

Following the spec w.r.t. your case...

- The `step` value is `0.010000000000000009` (from `parseFloat`).
- The `step-scale-factor` value is always `1` for `<input type="number" />`
- The `step-base` is the `min` attribute, which is `1.2`.
- The `allowed-value-step` is `step` * `step-scale-factor` which is `1 * 0.010000000000000009 === 0.010000000000000009`.
- Re: "Constraint validation", the spec says this:

  > **Constraint validation**: When the element has an `allowed-value-step`, and the result of applying the-algorithm-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number to the string given by the element's `value=""` is a number, and that number subtracted from the `step-base` is not an integral multiple of the `allowed-value-step`, the element is suffering from a step mismatch.

  I'll rephrase that to this...:

  - If element has `allowed-value-step` **and** numeric `value=""` attribute.

    - (So this is only *after* the `<input/>` is non-empty, such as clicking the up/down buttons *once* to give it a value of `1.2`)
    - ...then subtract `1.2` (the `step-base`) from `1.2` (the `value=""`) to give `0`.
    - And `0` is **not** an integral multiple of `0.010000000000000009`.
    - Therefore the element **is suffering from a step mismatch**.

Now, w.r.t. your findings:

> I can only click the button to increase the value once to fill in the `min` value

Yes, that follows the HTML5 spec: the initial `value=""` is empty, so browsers will choose the *next* valid highest value which is the `min="1.2"` value.

> and then only once for the first increase by the step value

Yes, that's because the *next* step is `1.2 + 0.010000000000000009` which is `1.210000000000000009` - which both browsers truncate the display to `1.21`, however **as soon as this happens** we see a difference in browser behaviour:

- **Firefox seems to correctly comply with the spec** and it sets  `HTMLInputElement.validity.stepMismatch` to `true` and disables the up/down buttons due to the step-mismatch condition.
- Chrome 92 does not and using the up/down buttons to set other values still results in `HTMLInputElement.validity.stepMismatch === false`.

---

Here's a snippet that shows validity information:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>input with decimal step</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="inp" type="number" min="1.2" max="1.3" step="0.010000000000000009" />

    <ul id="eventsList"></ul>

    <script>
    const inp = document.getElementById('inp');
    const ul  = document.getElementById('eventsList');

    inp.addEventListener( 'input', logInfo );
    inp.addEventListener( 'change', logInfo );
    inp.addEventListener( 'click', logInfo );

    function logInfo( e ) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = e.type + ". Value: " + inp.value + ", valid: " + inp.validity.valid + ", stepMismatch: " + inp.validity.stepMismatch;
        ul.appendChild( li );
    }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

- In Chrome, it lets me click the up button 10 times (`1.2`, `1.21`, `1.22`, `1.23`, ..., `1.28`, to `1.29`) before it stops, though it *never* reports `stepIsmatch: true`.
- In Firefox, it lets me click the up button 1 times (`1.2` and `1.21`) before it sets `stepMismatch: true`.

My money's on Chrome *doing their own thing* given their interpretation (or at least, their implementation) of the spec is more forgiving and is less likely to result in end-user-frustration when `step` is set to a *strange* value.

---

What's interesting is that the `Number` type in browsers seems able to accurately represent `0.010000000000000009` without any tell-tale IEEE 754 rounding (ditto Python), whereas C#/.NET's `Single` (32-bit) and `Double` (64-bit) floating-point types both choke and give me rather bad approximations.